# HTML5 DragNDrop - Drop event never fires

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I'm trying to implement a drag'n'drop upload input for a web app. Detecting drag start and end and appropriate drop target styling works flawlessly, though as soon as I drop an image file on the target, it opens in the browser. I know this has been asked pretty often on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere yet.

What I do see is: Listeners for `dragenter`, `dragstart` and `dragend` fire correctly, while `drop` does not. Please see the code below:

*(Note: The `app` object is just a simple, custom abstraction object, nothing special about it. The `app.on` method calls `addEventListener` and attaches the event wrapped in a try-catch block.)*

**Attaching the events**

```
app.on('drag dragover dragstart', app.elements.pictureDropArea, app.events.startedDragging, true);
app.on('dragenter', app.elements.pictureDropArea, app.events.isDragging);
app.on('dragleave dragend', app.elements.pictureDropArea, app.events.stoppedDragging);
app.on('drop', app.elements.pictureDropArea, app.events.isDropped);
```

**The individual events**

```
app.events.startedDragging = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
};

app.events.isDragging = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  app.elements.pictureDropArea.classList.add('dragged-over');
  return false;
};

app.events.stoppedDragging = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  app.elements.pictureDropArea.classList.remove('dragged-over');
  return false;
};

app.events.isDropped = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('drop event fired.');

  var file = event.dataTransfer.files[ 0 ];

  console.log(file);
  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it accidentally when I applied the same events to the `body`. It seems like there needs to a listener for `dragover` on the document body with the usual `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` stuff:

```
app.on('dragover', document.body, function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

*God, I hate this API so much...*

Comment: If you want a much better API and/or want to retain your sanity, try https://github.com/fresheneesz/drip-drop